# Prove the following more general version of Ascoli's theorem.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Prove the following more general version of Ascoli's theorem. Let E be a compact metric space and let K be a compact subset of a normed space X. Assume that a sequence of maps $\phi_n:E\to K$ is equicontinuous. Then the sequence $(\phi_n)_{n\geq 1}$ admits a uniformly convergent subsequence.

My solution:
similar to the proof of Ascoli Theorem:

Let $\varepsilon$ is given, $\exists\delta,s.t.d(x,y)<\delta \to |\phi_m(x)-\phi_m(y)|<\varepsilon ~~for~ \forall x,y\in E,~\forall m\geq 1 $. Since $E$ is compact, $E\subseteq\bigcup\limits_{i=1}^{n}B(X_i,\delta)$. Since $K$ is a compact subset, $M:=\max_{i\in\{1,\dots,n\}}\sup\limits_{m\geq 1}||\phi_m(x_i)||$. Choose finitelt many numbers $\alpha_1\dots,\alpha_l$ such that the balls $B(\alpha_j,\varepsilon)$ covers the compact interval $[-M,M]$

Consider the set $\Theta$ of all maps $\theta:\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}\to\{\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_l\}$ then we can construct the family of continuous functions
$$\phi_\theta:=\{\phi\in(\phi_n)_{n\geq1};||\phi(x_i)||\in B(\theta(x_i),\delta)~for~\forall~i=1,\dots,n\}.$$

Then we have $\bigcup\limits_{\theta\in\Theta}\phi_\theta=(\phi_n)_{n\geq1}$.
Since $(\phi_n)_{n\geq1}$ is precompact, thus the proof is complete.

This is similar to the proof of Ascoli, I want to know if this way can work.

Comment: This way may be hard to prove the conclusion, since $\phi(x)\in K$, but $\theta(x)\in \mathbb{R}.$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof works I think, however it's not really a more general version of Ascoli's theorem, as it can actually be seen as a corollary of it:

Consider $A := \{\phi_n, n \in \mathbb{N}^*\}$.
Since $K$ is compact, the sets $\{\phi_n(x), n \in \mathbb{N}^*\} \subset K$ are all relatively compact, and $A$ is equicontinuous due to the sequence being equicontinuous, and as such $A$ is relatively compact by Ascoli's theorem, which grants the existence of the sought after subsequence.

Comment: Thanks for you answer very much. Does the sets $\{\phi_n(x), n\in\mathbb{N}^*\}$ mean $B_x:=\{\phi_n(x);~n\in\mathbb{N}^*\}$, which means a series of sets(depend on $x$)? If so, why $B_x$ is relatively compact? I may lack of some knowledge. Or does it mean $\{\phi_n(x), n\in\mathbb{N}^*,~\forall x\in E\}$?

Comment: It's the former meaning. The reason they're relatively compact is because a closed subset of a compact set is also compact.

Comment: I'm confused that "A is equicontinuous " is known in the problem condition, how to obtain that $A$ is relatively compact? By Ascoli's theorem, I only know that "$\mathcal{F}\subset\mathcal{C}(E),...,$then$~\mathcal{F}$ is a relatively compact subset of \mathcal{C}(E) ", where $\mathcal{C}(E)$ means all continuous real-valued function on $E$.

Comment: Oh I see. The thing is, Ascoli's theorem can be [generalised](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arzel%C3%A0%E2%80%93Ascoli_theorem#Generalizations) to functions taking their values in arbitrary metric spaces, and that's what I was using, but I understand the confusion.